# Plain TeX floating Figures

Tags: floats, plain-tex

I wonder if someone can point me to some macros that effect floating figures. I'd like something along the lines of a footnote. i.e. auto-increment the Figure number and then create a floating box with caption. Something like `\figure#1#2#3#4` where the parameters are width, height, contents, caption. The ones I've looked at so far break the paragraph at the insertion point.

I'd like to say: "The plant shown in `\figure{3in}{4in}{\vfill}{Esparto grass}` grows in Spain and Algeria." which would introduce the floating vbox with a caption at the bottom prefixed by "Figure X", insert "Figure X" in the text.

I guess I need to study the `\topinsert` and `\footnote` code more closely... But maybe someone has done it already?

Comment: The Optex plain-tex format does this out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\newcount\figc
\long\def\figure#1#2#3#4{%
\ifhmode\unskip\vadjust\fi{\topinsert
\hrule width #1\relax
\vbox to #2{%
\hsize=#1\relax
\leftskip=\centering
\rightskip=\centering
\parindent=0pt %
\parfillskip=0pt %
\parskip=\baselineskip
#3
\par
\global\advance\figc1 %
{\bf Figure \the\figc}: #4\par
}%
\hrule width #1\relax
\endinsert}}


One two
\figure{2in}{3in}{\vfill XXX\vfill}{Sample one}
three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
\figure{3in}{1in}{\vfill XXX\vfill}{Sample two}
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white.

\bye
```

You may prefer to make the insert full width with a centered inner box the specified width but that would be a minor change, here I did as requested and made the insert the stated width.

Comment: Ah. Thank you! I think the \ifhmode\unskip\vadjust\fi is the missing piece to my puzzle